# How to perform a mathematical operation on two instances of object in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to add two numbers from two different objects.

Here is a simplified version. I have two integers and I multiply those to get `multiplied` .

models.py:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    number_a = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)
    number_b = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)

    def multiplied(self):
        return self.number_a * self.number_b
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def homeview(request):

    numbers = ModelA.objects.all()

    context = {
        'numbers': numbers,
    }
    return TemplateResponse...
```

What I'm trying to do is basically `multiplied + multiplied` in the template but I simply can't figure out how to do it since I first have to loop through the objects.

So if I had 2 instances of `ModelA` and `two 'multiplied' values of 100` I want to display `200` in the template. Is this possible?

Comment: And if you have 5 instances or 42 then what? Also show what you got in the template for now.

Comment: Sorry, but do you mean you want the output to be 10,000? 100 * 100? You describe addition but have coded multiplication. I'm very unsure of what you really want hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good practice is always to avoid logic on the template. It would be better to loop at the view and add calculated value to context:

```
def homeview(request):
    queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
    multipliers_addition = 0
    for obj in queryset:
        multipliers_addition += obj.multiplied()

    context = {
        'addition': multipliers_addition,
    }

    return render(request, 'multiply.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing that with [`aggregate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset)

```
from django.db.models import Sum

ModelA.objects.aggregate(Sum('multiplied'))
```

If that does not suit you just use `aggregate` on each `field` and then add them together.

Answer (score 2):

In your template, when you do a forloop over the `numbers` variable, you can directly access properties, functions and attributes.

So to access the value you want I guess it would look something like this, simplified:

```
{% for number in numbers %}
    {{ number.multiplied }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope that makes sense?

However, please take note that this is not the most efficient method.

We can make Django ask the SQL server to do the heavy lifting on the calculation side of things, so if you want to be really clever and optimise your view, you can comment out your `multiplied` function and replace then, you still access it in the template the same way I described above, but we needs to change the code in your view slightly like so:

```
numbers = ModelA.objects.aggregate(Sum('number_a', 'number_b'))
```

As described loosely in haduki's answer. This offloads the calculation to the SQL server by crafting an SQL query which uses the `SUM` SQL database function, which for all intents and purposes is almost always going to be substantially faster that having a function on the object.